# CSS double the width of all elements with media query (or jQuery)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, width

Below I have provided a jsfiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/cLvyydax/

I have a row of 8 divs (rather links that behave as divs) that are of different widths– they all add up to 100%. I have set it up so that when triggered by a media query of 600px width, it splits up into *two* equal rows, with each row at exactly 50% width. I have done so by inserting `<b></b>` tags in between the HTML 'divs' and setting it to `display: block` with the media query.

If every div were the same width, I could easily set the width to double with one single value.
However, being that these divs are of different widths (in percentages), how can I double the width of each div automatically when it splits into the two rows?

I tried by setting the parent/container element to a width of 200%, but this leaves a horizontal scrollbar and half the window blank. I also tried the `flex` method but this brings other problems with my setup.

How can I do this easily with CSS or Javascript/jQuery?

EDIT: I need a solution to have it done automatically

Result:

[image: Result]
[image: Scrollbar/Blank Space]

Desired Result:

[image: Desired Result]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Setting overflow to hidden should hide the scrollbar if the 200% otherwise works for you.  You can also set this on the parent to hide the blank space, if I understand that problem correctly.

```
aside {
  width:200%;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}
```

Edited:

```
aside {
   width:200%;
   box-sizing: border-box;
}
div {
    position:relative;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    max-width: 100%;
    overflow-x:hidden;
    min-height: 120px;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/5cz84od0/4

Needs `position:relative` on parent element and a `min-height` on the parent element to force the parent element to expand to the same size as the `aside`.
Ah, and I did put the overflow-x on the wrong element the first time - of course on the element that is overflowing won't work! I was thinking about it being the container of the `a`s...

UPDATE:
Fiddle adjusted per comments: https://jsfiddle.net/5cz84od0/6/
Works with just `div` around `aside` and a little bit of CSS.

Comment: It still leaves the blank space and scrollbar.. I tested it on jsfiddle on Safari and Chrome, as well as a live-preview of my website .. You can check out Mindless's jsfiddle it doesn't work there either. I also updated my post with a screenshot

Comment: Seems to be "broken"– the divs no longer go back to a single row as intended

Comment: I moved the`b` out of the media query because it wouldn't go to two lines on my iPad otherwise. That might be your issue.

Comment: I put it back in the media query and tried fixing it but there's a weird spacing issue it doesn't all stay in one row anymore.. also I would hope the code works on your iPad too lol

Comment: It was making the screen "wider" at first because of the overflowing aside.  Also, I have now discovered how to change the width on the fiddle sections. The reason for the spacing issue is the line break I added in the HTML so that I could see past the tag in the upper-right corner - as inline-block, it leaves space for spaces like that.  If you put the HTML on one line again, it works as expected. :-)

Comment: This works, but how do I remove the margin? I removed the border but there seems to be like a 10px margin all around, is there anyway to remove/offset that?

Comment: `body {
    margin:0;
}`

Comment: I got it to work. Thanks! Accepted answer, it's actually the cleanest and simplest one

Answer (score 1):

Why not remove b tag and just do this, since you are defining width of each a tag already, just double them.

```css
aside {
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0;
}

aside a {
  height: 50px;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
}

/*widths and colors*/
a:nth-of-type(1) {width: 8.33%; background-color: hsl(0,100%,75%);}
a:nth-of-type(2) {width: 16.66%; background-color: hsl(20,100%,60%);}
a:nth-of-type(3) {width: 8.33%; background-color: hsl(40,100%,75%);}
a:nth-of-type(4) {width: 8.33%; background-color: hsl(60,100%,60%);}
a:nth-of-type(5) {width: 8.33%; background-color: hsl(80,100%,65%);}
a:nth-of-type(6) {width: 16.66%; background-color: hsl(150,100%,60%);}
a:nth-of-type(7) {width: 8.33%; background-color: hsl(260,100%,75%);}
a:nth-of-type(8) {width: 24.99%; background-color: hsl(0,100%,80%);}

@media only screen and (max-width: 500px) {
a:nth-of-type(1) {width: 16.66%; }
a:nth-of-type(2) {width: 33.32%; }
a:nth-of-type(3) {width: 16.66%; }
a:nth-of-type(4) {width: 16.66%; }
a:nth-of-type(5) {width: 16.66%; }
a:nth-of-type(6) {width: 33.32%; }
a:nth-of-type(7) {width: 16.66%; }
a:nth-of-type(8) {width: 49.98%; }
}
```

```html
<aside><a></a><a></a><a></a><a></a><a></a><a></a><a></a><a></a><a></a><a></a><a></a><a></a></aside>
```

**Update**

Seems like the only way to do it is through jquery, on resize action, when width is <= 500, double the width of each a tag and set trigger to true so it doesn't do it again, when width is > 500, divide current width by 2 and set trigger to false so when width is <= 500, it doubles the width again.

**Update 2**

Added toFixed(2) to width percentage, so it's a constant double decimal place, otherwise it is a four decimal place width percentage and it changes overtime after serveral resize.

```js
var minWidthTriggered = false;
var maxWidthTriggered = false;

$(window).resize(function(){
  if ($(window).width() <= 500 && !minWidthTriggered){ 
    minWidthTriggered = true;
    maxWidthTriggered = true;

    $("a").each(function(){
      widthPercentage = $(this).width() / $(this).parent().width() * 100;

      $(this).css({
        'width' : widthPercentage.toFixed(2) * 2 + "%"
      });
    });
  } 
  else if ($(window).width() > 500 && maxWidthTriggered)
  {
    maxWidthTriggered = false;
    minWidthTriggered = false;

    $("a").each(function(){
      widthPercentage = $(this).width() / $(this).parent().width() * 100;

      $(this).css({
        'width' : widthPercentage.toFixed(2) / 2 + "%"
      });
    });
  }
});
```

```css
aside {
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0;
}

aside a {
  height: 50px;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
}

/*widths and colors*/
a:nth-of-type(1) {width: 8.33%; background-color: hsl(0,100%,75%);}
a:nth-of-type(2) {width: 16.66%; background-color: hsl(20,100%,60%);}
a:nth-of-type(3) {width: 8.33%; background-color: hsl(40,100%,75%);}
a:nth-of-type(4) {width: 8.33%; background-color: hsl(60,100%,60%);}
a:nth-of-type(5) {width: 8.33%; background-color: hsl(80,100%,65%);}
a:nth-of-type(6) {width: 16.66%; background-color: hsl(150,100%,60%);}
a:nth-of-type(7) {width: 8.33%; background-color: hsl(260,100%,75%);}
a:nth-of-type(8) {width: 24.99%; background-color: hsl(0,100%,80%);}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.js"></script>
<aside><a></a><a></a><a></a><a></a><a></a><a></a><a></a><a></a></aside>
```

Comment: I have a row like this on each of my pages and I need to change the width often, I need a solution to have it done automatically. it also occupies way too much code

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/qp42jzc6/, and remember to clear your cache, you idea of setting aside to width 200% seems to work

Comment: Doesn't work, scrollbar and blank space still there =(

Comment: What browser are you using, do you have a live demo?

Comment: Tested on Safari and Chrome, on the linked jsfiddle and my website

Comment: I tested this on Chrome, it doesn't leave a blank space, do you have a screenshot?

Comment: Seems like the whole content moves to the left, hence the scrollbar as well, you are using a mac i think, might be mac related.

Comment: Yes I am, and the content doesn't move to the left but the scroll and blank space is still there (the screenshot was taken after I scrolled a bit)

Comment: i tried transform: scaleX(2), it transform along the x axies, but it overlaps each other, so that needs to be addressed, something worth a try

Comment: I just tried that too haha, I solved the overlap by adding margin-left and margin-right 4.16%– but then it stretches the content inside of it

Comment: I think i figured something out, just finishing it up

Comment: hmm, not perfect yet, i will keep going with this, the width changes after multiple resize action

Comment: fixed the problem, please check answer

Comment: This does a thing, which is great, but I'm betting there is a different way to think about this that is much more simple.

Comment: Yes, transform: scaleX(2) might work with some addtional css, but i couldn't figure out how without changing current html and css. Remember it has to work on all a tags and each a tags has different width.

Comment: @sheriffderek You could check out my answer, which only adds a little CSS and a div.  Someone downvoted it because I goofed up my first response, but it works now.

Comment: @ErinHalbmaier - I think that was me. I removed the downvote - but I don't think that is a good answer. I also don't think this is a good question though...

Comment: @sheriffderek - Personally, I'd use classes (rather than nth-of-type ) to set the widths and then double them in a media query - possibly letting SASS do the calculation for me - or else wrap each group in a div and change the width on that, but I was trying to work with what the OP had going. :-)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not clear on what you want to happen... but what about this - as a starter?

https://codepen.io/sheriffderek/pen/a88b66fa934e4abbd38e054a45d3f2ff

markup for a list of things... which is what you have.

```
<ul class='thing-list'>
  <li class='thing one'>
    <a href='' class='link'>.</a>
  </li>
  <li class='thing two'></li>
  <li class='thing three'></li>
  <li class='thing four'></li>
  <li class='thing five'></li>
  <li class='thing six'></li>
  <li class='thing seven'></li>
  <li class='thing eight'></li>
</ul>
```

I'd highly recommend using Stylus for your CSS - but compiled CSS is below

```
/* apply a natural box layout model to all elements, but allowing components to change */
html
    box-sizing: border-box
*, *:before, *:after
    box-sizing: inherit

.thing-list
    display: flex
    flex-direction: row
    flex-wrap: wrap
    .thing
        min-height: 90px
        flex-basis: (1/12)*100%
        &.one
            background: hsl(0,100%,75%)
        &.two
            flex-basis: (2/12)*100%
            background: hsl(20,100%,60%)
        &.three
            background: hsl(40,100%,75%)
        &.four
            background: hsl(60,100%,60%)
        &.five
            background: hsl(80,100%,65%)
        &.six
            flex-basis: (2/12)*100%
            background: hsl(150,100%,60%)
        &.seven
            background: hsl(260,100%,75%)
        &.eight
            flex-basis: (3/12)*100%
            background: hsl(0,100%,80%)
        .link
            display: block
            color: inherit
            text-decoration: none
            width: 100%
            min-height: 90px
            // i'd prabably color the link - not the li

    @media (min-width: 600px)
        .thing
            flex-basis: (2/12)*100%
            &.two
                flex-basis: (4/12)*100%
            &.six
                flex-basis: (4/12)*100%
            &.eight
                flex-basis: (6/12)*100%
```

CSS

```
/* apply a natural box layout model to all elements, but allowing components to change */
html {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
*,
*:before,
*:after {
  box-sizing: inherit;
}
.thing-list {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-orient: horizontal;
  -webkit-box-direction: normal;
      -ms-flex-direction: row;
          flex-direction: row;
  -ms-flex-wrap: wrap;
      flex-wrap: wrap;
}
.thing-list .thing {
  min-height: 90px;
  -ms-flex-preferred-size: 8.333333333333332%;
      flex-basis: 8.333333333333332%;
}
.thing-list .thing.one {
  background: #ff8080;
}
.thing-list .thing.two {
  -ms-flex-preferred-size: 16.666666666666664%;
      flex-basis: 16.666666666666664%;
  background: #f73;
}
.thing-list .thing.three {
  background: #ffd480;
}
.thing-list .thing.four {
  background: #ff3;
}
.thing-list .thing.five {
  background: #c3ff4d;
}
.thing-list .thing.six {
  -ms-flex-preferred-size: 16.666666666666664%;
      flex-basis: 16.666666666666664%;
  background: #3f9;
}
.thing-list .thing.seven {
  background: #aa80ff;
}
.thing-list .thing.eight {
  -ms-flex-preferred-size: 25%;
      flex-basis: 25%;
  background: #f99;
}
.thing-list .thing .link {
  display: block;
  color: inherit;
  text-decoration: none;
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 90px;
}
@media (min-width: 600px) {
  .thing-list .thing {
    -ms-flex-preferred-size: 16.666666666666664%;
        flex-basis: 16.666666666666664%;
  }
  .thing-list .thing.two {
    -ms-flex-preferred-size: 33.33333333333333%;
        flex-basis: 33.33333333333333%;
  }
  .thing-list .thing.six {
    -ms-flex-preferred-size: 33.33333333333333%;
        flex-basis: 33.33333333333333%;
  }
  .thing-list .thing.eight {
    -ms-flex-preferred-size: 50%;
        flex-basis: 50%;
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but the problem is I literally have a CSS file with almost 500 lines of code for each and every "block" on each of my 20 pages.  Having to manually adjust the original percentage and @media percentage every time I need to make changes would not only be extremely time consuming, but would also double my CSS file size and slow my website down.  I was hoping for a few lines of code to do it automatically, and I'm now seeing it may have to be jQuery, but I don't know how..

Comment: Sounds like there is a much bigger problem then. You'll have to find a better pattern. You can add classes to certain items with jQuery - or with nth-of-type... but your problem isn't explained well enough for me to help.